# Многопоточный прием данных

Tags: c#, многопоточность, smtp

Есть СМТП-сервис. Он слушает 25ый порт:

```
SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 25); 
SMTP_Listener.Start();
```

Получается, что когда к нему шлют команды 2 и более клиентов, то они "сливаются" и получается такое (пример):

> - Клиент1: команда "HELLO 11111"
> - Клиент2: команда "HELLO 22222"
> - Клиент3: команда "HELLO 33333"

Я получаю "HELLO 11" от первого клиента, от второго- "LO 22", для третьего - "LO 3333" (например).

**Подскажите, как правильно разделить чтение от нескольких клиентов?**

У меня каждый клиент работает в отдельном потоке.

КОД приема сообщений от клиентов:

```
/// <summary>
/// Считываем команду клиента
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private string ReadLine() {
    try {
        long lastDataTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        ArrayList lineBuf = new ArrayList();
        byte prevByte = 0;

        while (true) {
            if (clientSocket == null) l.Write(" !!! clientSocket is NULL");

            if (!clientSocket.Connected) l.Write(" !!! сокет не включен!");

            if (clientSocket.Available > 0) {
                // Read next byte
                byte[] currByte = new byte[1];
                int countRecieved = clientSocket.Receive(currByte, 1, SocketFlags.None);

                // Count must be equal. Eg. some computers won't give byte at first read attempt
                if (countRecieved == 1) {
                    lineBuf.Add(currByte[0]);

                    // Line found
                    if ((prevByte == (byte)
                    '\r' && currByte[0] == (byte)
                    '\n')) {
                        byte[] retVal = new byte[lineBuf.Count - 2]; // Remove <CRLF> 
                        lineBuf.CopyTo(0, retVal, 0, lineBuf.Count - 2);

                        return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(retVal).Trim();
                    }

                    // Store byte
                    prevByte = currByte[0];
                    //l.Write("prevByte = " + prevByte);
                    //// Check if maximum length is exceeded
                    //if (lineBuf.Count > maxLen)
                    //{
                    //    throw new Exception( "Maximum line length exceeded");
                    //}

                    // reset last data time
                    lastDataTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                    //l.Write("lastDataTime = " + lastDataTime);
                }
            } else {
                // l.Write("clientSocket.Available: " + clientSocket.Available.ToString()); // тут всегда 0
                //---- Time out stuff -----------------------//
                if (DateTime.Now.Ticks > lastDataTime + ((long)(60000)) * 10000) {
                    l.Write("ERROR: Read timeout: " + (((long)(60000)) * 10000).ToString());

                    //clientSocket.Close();
                    l.Write("Сокет закрыт из-за простоя в " + (((long)(60000)) * 10000).ToString() + " м-сек.");

                    // throw new Exception("Read timeout");
                    return ""; // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                //------------------------------------------//
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception x) {
        l.Write("EROR ReadLine(): " + x.ToString());
        throw new Exception(x.Message);
    }
}
```

> **UPD:**

```
 public void Listen()
        {
            int iter = 0;

            try
            {
                l.Write("***************START*******************");
                l.Write("SMTP server started " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port); 
                SMTP_Listener.Start();


                while (true)
                {

//тут я определяю что у нас есть клиент
                    clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();                

                    _sessionId = clientSocket.GetHashCode().ToString();

                    _email.sessionId = Convert.ToInt32(_sessionId);

                    l.Write("New session: " + _sessionId);

//и в отдельный поток его
                    Thread newClient = new Thread(StartProcessing);

                    l.Write("Создан поток для обработки клиента " + _sessionId);
                    UserSessionController.AddSession( Convert.ToInt32(_sessionId ) );

                    newClient.Name = _sessionId;
                    newClient.IsBackground = true; // ???
                    newClient.Start();          
                } 

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                l.Write("SMTP Listen Error: " + ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: (1) Проблема в том, как вы соотносите подсоединившийся клиент и вашу процедуру `ReadLine`. Неужели у вас общий `clientSocket` на всех?

Comment: (2) Очень низкоуровневый код. Вы бы что ли перешли на `NetworkStream` и пользовались какими-то более высокоуровневыми функциями.

Comment: @ VladD, да clientSocket  общий. Это не правильно? Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, в этом в общем-то и проблема. А как у вас происходит Accept?

Comment: В смысле прием сообщений от клиента? В том потоке, в котором обслуживается клиент запускается ReadLine(). Я ответил на Ваш вопрос?

Comment: Не-а. Какой код заведует Accept'ом, когда приходит новое соединение? Где в вашем коде вы узнаёте, что пришёл новый клиент? Эта часть важна.

Comment: сейчас обновлю вопрос куском кодом, минуточку

Comment: Обновил вопрос - добавил код, который "ловит" клиентов

Comment: @LeonardBertone clientSocket - статический? если это поле класса - то экземпляр класса один на всех?

Comment: нет, не статический. он объявлен как : private Socket clientSocket

Comment: @LeonardBertone а, тогда понятно в чем проблема. сейчас попробую написать ответ.

Comment: Ну тогда понятно, вы затираете старый сокет. Вы должны заводить каждый раз новую переменную, и отдавать её обрабатывающему потоку.

Comment: Вы про эту строчку : clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private Socket clientSocket
```

у вас один общий экземпляр сокета для всех клиентов.

когда подключается новый клиент

```
clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();
```

вы выбрасываете сокет, который был открыт при подключении предыдущего клиента. В результате все потоки у вас читают из this.clientSocket, ссылающегося на сокет, открытый для последнего подключенного клиента.

Т.е. все, что прислали предыдущие клиенты, но что не успели вычитать - уходит вникуда. А все, что присылает последний клиент, рвут между собой все читающие потоки.

Вам стоит перенести код, связанный с обработкой клиента, в отдельный класс, чтобы получить отдельный экземпляр на каждого клиента:

```
class ClientProcessor()
{
    private Socket clientSocket;
    public ClientProcessor(Socket clientSocket)
    {
       this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }
    string ReadLine() {....}
    void StartProcessing();
}
```

и создавать новый экземпляр для каждого подключившегося клиента:

```
var processor = new ClientProcessor(SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket());                

Thread newClient = new Thread(processor.StartProcessing);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Проблема решена, спасибо!!!!!!!